# Matplotlib Hist TypeError

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in a Jupyter Notebook (Python 2.7.5):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.hist([1,2,3,4])
```

and when I run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-03f4be6ff26b> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.hist([1,2,3,4])

System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, hold, **kwargs)
   2339         ax.hold(hold)
   2340     try:
-> 2341         ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
   2342         draw_if_interactive()
   2343     finally:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
   7734             # this will automatically overwrite bins,
   7735             # so that each histogram uses the same bins
-> 7736             m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)
   7737             if normed:
   7738                 db = np.diff(bins)

TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new'
```

The other types of plots (e.g. scatterplots) are working fine in the notebook. Has anyone encountered this error before? Thanks.

Update: Numpy version is 1.10.4 and matplotlib version is 1.1.1.

Comment: perhaps you are referring to some other code as you are not using histogram() function? (nor there is any argument 'new') can u give the exact code block which gives you this error? the 3 lines u give no error on my machine but give me simple histogram

Comment: It always helps to provide the **full** errortraceback, not only the last line of it. Usually this error should not happen, so something is wrong on your system. In addition to the full traceback it would therefore help to include the versions of matplotlib and numpy you are using. Possibly they are incompatible.